# Time out after x amount of seconds discord.py rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a bot in discord.py rewrite and made a embed creator in your dm's and want to make it so if you dont respond in x amount of seconds the bot says "Where did you go? We can try this again later."

Here is my current code:

```
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    em = discord.Embed(description=f"Embed Creation started in dm {ctx.author.mention}",color = discord.Colour.red())
    await ctx.send(embed=em, delete_after=3)
    em = discord.Embed(description='What would you like the title to be?', color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    title = msg.content
    em = discord.Embed(description='What would you like the Description to be?', color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    desc = msg.content
    get_channel = ctx.channel
    em = discord.Embed(title="**Set Channel for Embed to send**", description = f"1 - `{get_channel}`\n2 - Other Location.", color = discord.Colour.red())
    await user.send(embed=em)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if msg.content == "1":
      channel = ctx.channel
      em = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc,color=discord.Colour.red())
      em.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Embed Created by: {ctx.author.name}")
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = em)
    elif msg.content == "2":
      em = discord.Embed(description="Enter Channel ID", color = discord.Colour.red())
      await user.send(embed=em)
      text_channel = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
      channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=text_channel)
      em = discord.Embed(title=title, description=desc,color=discord.Colour.red())
      em.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Embed Created by: {ctx.author.name}")
      await ctx.send(embed=em)
    return
  else:
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Permissions Required!", description = f"{ctx.author.name} You do not have the required Permissions to use this command", color = discord.Colour.red())
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timeout argument in client.wait_for, and you will get something like that.
You must import asyncio, to make it work

```py
try:
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=x) #x - your seconds
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("Where did you go? We can try this again later.")
else:
    #your code, if the user managed to enter values
```

Comment: this code works however... the bot takes Where did you go we can try this again later and puts it as a title, description

Comment: I replaced ctx with user if that helps